# Ticket Booking System: Comparing two strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Okay so I'm basically trying to verify whether the username being entered is a duplicate but there's a problem in the string comparison inside the while loop

I tried using a temp label to verify that the values are being extracted correctly.

```
protected void BtnConfirmSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int f = 0;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLlocalDB;Initial Catalog=traveller;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader read;

    /*DEBUG: Prevent duplicate usernames*/

    try
    {
        Session["user"] = TxtUsrName.Text;
        Session["pass"] = TxtPsswd.Text;
        Session["email"] = TxtEmail.Text;

        //Label6.Text = "Faf";
        //  if ((Label6.Text).Equals(TxtUsrName.Text))
        //{
        //  Label6.Text = "dafuqqqq";
        //}
        //{
        //  Label6.Text = "wtf";
        //   Label6.Text = TxtUsrName.Text;
        //}

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name from Useriden", con);
        con.Open();
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            Label6.Text = read["Name"].ToString();
            Label1.Text = "aaa";
            //Label6.Text = "Faf";
            if ((Label6.Text).Equals(TxtUsrName.Text))
            {
                f = 1;
                //Label6.Text = "Duplicate Username";
                break;
            }
        }

        if (f == 1)
        {
            Label6.Text = "Duplicate Username";
        }
        else if (f == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SignUpNext.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        LabelUserName.Visible = true;
        LabelUserName.Text = ex.Message;
        con.Close();
        ViewState["Caption"]=ex.Message;                
    }
}
```

Expected: I'm entering a duplicate name so it should the change the text of the label to Duplicate Username but it instead navigates to the next page/The value of f never changes.

Comment: Use the F9 key to put a breakpoint on `if ((Label6.Text).Equals(TxtUsrName.Text))`. Use the debugger's watch window to compare the strings in the two text boxes, or just hover the mouse over them. Are they the "same", but with different capitalization? .Equals() will tell you that "A" and "a" are two different strings. `Label6.Text.Equals(TxtUsrName.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` will ignore capitalization.

Comment: @EdPlunkett They are exactly the same. I used the string "Faf" for both of them.

Comment: You need to step through the code in the debugger. Maybe no rows are coming back from the query, and the while loop never executes. I can't be sure what the deal is since I don't have all your code and I don't have any of your database, but stepping through in the debugger should clarify a lot.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The statement Label6.Text = read["Name"].ToString(); inside the while loop is being executed so it's most definitely going inside the loop. I'll step through the code in the debugger then Ig.

Comment: Are you really creating an additional unneeded Label just because you didn't want to declare a local string variable? That's a really strange thing to do.

Comment: Make sure you are definitely confirming the values in those two labels in the watch window in the debugger at runtime. When you just *know* what they *ought* to be, you're usually wrong. And by "you" I mean "everybody".

Comment: @Legendary Also dispose of your connection by wrapping it in a using. I'd also use the async versions of those ADO.NET methods as well.

Comment: Aside: Having the database perform the check by using a parameterized query would be more efficient: `select case when exists ( select 42 from Useriden where Name = @UsrNameStringFrmInptTextBx ) then 1 else 0 end as UserExists;`.

Comment: William is right, and you should do the same with the Command and the Reader. Now: You asked [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551657/ticket-booking-system-database-access-issue) 15 hours ago. Nothing has changed, and you're still claiming that "Faf".Equals("Faf") returns false. **It doesn't return false**.

Comment: Please update your original question with more details rather than opening a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @EdPlunkett pointed out with the Ordinal Case... You should also make sure there are no extra spaces.

```
Label6.Trim().Text.Equals(TxtUsrName.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Side note: You also don't seem to be closing your SqlConnection unless there is an exception. You should maybe use using()